# Propositional Resolution Question

Tags: propositional-calculus

Given the premises $(p ⇒ q)$ and $(r ⇒ s)$, use Propositional Resolution to prove the conclusion $(p ∨ r ⇒ q ∨ s)$.

Comment: Do you know how the [Resolution proof procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_propositional_logic) works ?

Comment: I tried to use this procedure but I'm still confused ... :-(

Comment: You have to start with the two premises rewritten as *clauses*, e.g. $\lnot p \lor q$, and the **negation** of the conclusion, i.e. $(p \lor r) \land \lnot (q \lor s)$.

Comment: Thanks! I will try again.

Comment: Thank you, Mauro! I was able to solve this exercise in a very easy way! I was a little lost between commands. This is the first time that I study this procedure and I need to practice more! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

(⇒)  and (⇒) mean that the premises are {~p,q} and {-r,s}.
For the conclusion  (∨⇒∨), we should get its negated conclusions:

1. ~(p|r => q|s)
2. ~~(p|r)|~(q|s)
3. (p|r)|(~q & ~s)
4. {p,r}, {~q}, {~s}

Now we can use Propositional Resolution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2VZd.jpg)